# Install MySQLi and pgsql extensions on PHP 7.0.7

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, mysqli, installation

My php.ini extentions section is like as follows

```
    ; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5+)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=php_snmp.dll

;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

I'm using PhpStorm to host PHP.
Whenever I try to run the function i get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in **archive** Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **archive**
```

And my code looks like follows:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","aula") or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_query($con, 'SET NAMES utf8') or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

On the second line I already get the error. How can I install the extensions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure both `extension=php_mysql.dll` and `extension=php_mysqli.dll`  are uncommented in `php.in`,  `mysqli` is the "improved" MySQL library but that does not necessarily mean it replaces the `mysql library` entirely.

Also please make sure you set right php PATH environment variable.

Comment: you mean the extension `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`?

Comment: @Marcelo43, yes...Did you get it work by trying the above

Comment: No... But i'm downloading XAMPP with PHP 7 now. When I used XAMPP before it worked

Comment: @Marcelo43 Yes, I have been using XAMPP for years with PHP 5+ and it works flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 0):

change from

**extension_dir = "ext"**

to

**extension_dir = "C:\Apache24\php\ext"**

Answer (score 0):

(Working on windows)

I was facing exactly the same issue.

In my case, the problem was that I had saved the php.ini file as a text file. As soon as I converted the text file to "All Files" in notepad and gave it the ".ini" extension, it became a "Configuration Settings File" and it worked.

You may check if this is the case by going through the loaded configuration file row in phpinfo(). If the value is 'none', you may be facing a similar issue.

Note: I had already uncommented the extensions and fixed the extension directory.